# Show value instead of text in Knockout-bound dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm having an HTML dropdown, where I use Knockout.js to bind the options. With the dropdown, you can select ISO country codes. In the (short) dropdown, I want to display the two-letter country code as text. The full names of the countries should only appear, when the user opens the dropdown. Something like:

```
+=======+===+
| DE    | v |
+=======+===+
| Germany   |
| England   |
| France    |
| Spain     |
| USA       |
+-----------+
```

Right now, my HTML code looks like this:

```html
<select class="form-control w-25" data-bind="
    value: customAddress.country,
    options: countryList,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'code',
    optionsCaption: 'Country'
" required></select>
```

Obviously, the dropdown displays "Germany" right now, if you select it. I found some ideas to replace the display text of the dropdown using jQuery in the onBlur event. But I fear, that this will interfere with the data binding mechanism of knockout (all properties are observables).

How can I solve that? Do I need a custom binding?

Comment: please share your view model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a custom binding handler (and certainly don't need to resort to jQuery); this could be accomplished using the default binding handlers.

1. Store the select menu state (open/closed) in a variable;
2. Toggle this variable on the blur/focus events using the `event` binding. If it's a `focus` event, we assume the menu is open; if it's a `blur` event, we assume menu is closed.
3. Pass a function to `optionsText` that will return either the code or the country, depending on the value of said variable.

JS:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.countries = [{
      code: 'DE',
      country: 'Germany'
    },
    {
      code: 'NL',
      country: 'The Netherlands'
    },
    {
      code: 'BE',
      country: 'Belgium'
    }
  ];

  vm.countrySelectIsOpen = ko.observable(false);
  vm.selectedCountry = ko.observable();

  vm.getOptionsText = function(item) {
    return item[vm.countrySelectIsOpen() ? 'country' : 'code'];
  }

  vm.toggleCountrySelectStatus = function(data, event) {
    vm.countrySelectIsOpen(event.type === 'focus');
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" data-bind="
        options: countries,
        optionsText: getOptionsText,
        optionsValue: 'code',
        optionsCaption: 'Country',
        value: selectedCountry,
        event: {
            blur: toggleCountrySelectStatus,
            focus: toggleCountrySelectStatus
        }
    "></select>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/hf70kg84/

Comment: This is a pretty clever solution, I have to say! There is one slight imperfection, though: The blur event happens, when the dropdown loses focus, not when it closes. That means, from the time between clicking on an entry and clicking on something else on the page, it will still show the long text. Is there another event, that fires immediately after closing the dropdown?

Comment: add `change: blurWhenSelected` to the `event: {}` bind and in your viewmodel `vm.blurWhenSelected = function(data, event) { event.currentTarget.blur(); };` to probably fix that 'slight imperfection' :)

Comment: I've posted a follow up question to this. Maybe you have an idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394539/problem-on-ios-safari-when-replacing-select-options-on-the-fly